# Why do subsequent update calls to GPUImageUIElement result in black output?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

**Problem**: I'm trying to apply a gaussian blur to a changing `UIView` and display the live blurred result using GPUImage. Currently many of GPUImage's filters work perfectly, but `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter`behaves differently in a strange way. After a second `update` call of `GPUImageUIElement` without re-instantiating the input, and filter, the resulting output is black and blank.

**Example**:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // blurInput --> blurFilter --> blurOutput
    GPUImageUIElement          *blurInput  = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:self.changingView];
    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageView               *blurOutput = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    [blurInput  addTarget:self.blurFilter];
    [blurFilter addTarget:self.blurOutput];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.blurOutput];

    [blurInput update];
 }
```

**What Happens**: At this point the blur is working, but a subsequent call to `[blurInput update]` (ie. from the underlying `self.changingView` when it updates) results in the `blurOutput` view turning black …unless I re-instantiate `blurIntput`/`blurFilter`, add their targets again, and call `[blurInput update]`. This isn't necessary with many of GPUImage's other filters.

---

**Notes**:

- *The part of the `changingView` that is updating is it's gradient layer (CAGradientLayer)*
- In my actual code the three GPUImage variables are held as strong ivars.